# Ajax data returned to Symfony partial_include that is recognized by current jQuery / DOM?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony1

I am trying to get the return ajax data to be recognized by jQuery.  I am able to interact with jQuery when the page loads by having the content load in between the div tag like so:

```
<div id="edit-features-id">
  include_partial(
    'user/favoritesEditFavorites', 
    array('vrs_allfav_data' => $vrs_allfav_data)
    );
</div>
```

This div tag is attached to a jQuery dialog . And to make things more interesting the dialog was opened by the dialog before it. For explanation only lets call the first dialog ( ListView ) and the second dialog ( EditMode ).

Therefore when the page loads the include_partial loads the include_partial in between the div tags therefore when the EditMode is opened jQuery recognizes jQuery commands.  It works as you are able to delete, modify and reorder the data but nothing happens until you click save.

When you click save, the data is posted with ajax, updates database and if successful returns an alert confirmation.  When alert is closed then it does this:

- closes the EditMode dialog
- first function updates the ListView dialog div tag
- second function updates the EditView dialog div tag

Since the ListView is for view it loads the new data that was saved and it is good to go. When the EditMode dialog is called by the ListView this time, nothing is interactive with jQuery as you no longer able to click or sort now in EditMode.

The content returned is loaded into the EditMode dialog div tags replacing the current html information that was loaded there by the partial_include on page load:

```
<div id="edit-features-id"></div>
```

I have successful loaded the content between the div tags using these different ways to get the data for EditMode:

NOTE: I am using **var $j = jQuery.noConflict();**

```
favoritesReloadEditFavorites = function() {
  $j.ajax({
    url: favoritesEditFavoritesURL,
      cache: false
      }).done(function(html) {
      $j('#vrs_favorites_edit').append(html);
  });
};
```

or like this:

```
$j('#vrs_favorites_edit').load(favoritesEditFavoritesURL);
```

or like this:

```
$j.ajax({
  url: favoritesEditFavoritesURL,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    $j('#vrs_favorites_edit').html(response);
  };
});
```

As you noticed they all go to favoritesEditFavoritesURL which translates to this symfony 1.3.11 route "user/favoritesEditFavorites" which calls this action:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
  // Retrieve data from db $vrs_allfav_data loaded into EditMode using renderPartial.
  return $this->renderPartial(
    'user/favoritesEditFavorites', 
    array('vrs_allfav_data' => $vrs_allfav_data)
  );
}
```

This works great to load content but not content that needs to be interactive with jQuery in order to allow clicks as well as drag and drop capability.

With that being said I was able to find a solution to resolve the jQuery click function to allow it to start working by changing my jQuery .on code from this:

```
$j('.cancelEditFavorites').on('click', function() {
```

to this:

```
$j(document).on('click', '.cancelEditFavorites', function() {
```

Unfortunately the drag and drop aka sortable does not work which does nested sorting by using this jquery plugin [jquery_sortable](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) and the code below:

```
$j("ol.vertical").sortable({
    group: 'favorites',
    handle: '.handle',
    isValidTarget: function($item, container) {
        if ($item.is(".link")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return $item.parent("ol")[0] == container.el[0];
        }
    },
    onDragStart: function($item, container, _super) {
        if ($item.is(".folder")) {
            $j('ol.vertical ol').sortable('disable');
            _super($item, container);
        }
    },
    onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {
        if ($item.is(".folder")) {
            $j('ol.vertical ol').sortable('enable');
            _super($item, container);
        }
    },
});
```

And finally my question, Is there a way to load the data from the ajax or any other type call that will be recognized by the dom thus allowing it to be interactive with jQuery like it was on initial load or would be if it was a refreshed page?

Refreshing the browser is doable but will cause both dialogs to disappear and leave the end user thinking what just happened as now they will have to reclick to open the first dialog to reopen the second which to me is not a good user experience.

Comment: Just to be clear you have a 'View Mode' page which users click somewhere to edit and that brings up a dialog which is the 'Edit Mode' version of the page?  Plus the dialog view of the 'Edit Mode' version  does not functional javascript logic?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the reason why it would not work is because the Ajax call was bringing in new data that jQuery could not use as the page was already loaded therefore I added onclick to the buttons of the new content that loaded which when fired were recognized by the jQuery thus solving my problem.